# How do I send a url to a database after it is clicked using PHP and a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "test", "test");
mysql_select_db("test");

// yada yada ..code ...


echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link . "' target='_blank'>" . $item_title . "</a>");


$sql = mysql_query("insert into myTable(item_link , item_title ,) values('$item_link ', '$item_title ')");


mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: your echo is outputting the values of `$item_link` and `$item_title` to the page. they'll insert that data just fine if you assigned them values somewhere in your  `// yada yada ..code ...` code section (while ignoring your non paramatized array)

Comment: first don't use deprecated and removed `mysql_*` library. turn to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Also it's unclear what you really want to achieve

Comment: No, they have values. the each is print out a link and I want that link to trigger the insert. How do I get code that into the link

Comment: Your question looks incomplete. Post what you need exact. Use mysqli_* as suggested by @Anant

Comment: I just want that link that gets echoed to trigger the insert. Im not sure i wrote it right.

Comment: After link click if you want to trigger insert then:- 1. create a new page which your  link have, like suppose your link is `<a href="abc.php">` then create abc.php  and write the insert query there.2 Or on the link click just use ajax to send link and title to a php page and do the insert code there (then your link page will not refreshed)

Comment: If the link is in the same page you could write using the $_REQUEST for inserting into the DB . if it points to another page you can't write it in this page to insert.

Comment: in that case on the page you link to you either put in some code that gets the [current url](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6768793/1028804) and run your query on that page or you use javascript to ajax to a php file sending the url to it and having it insert before you move off the page